# Zoom-in or Zoom-out HTML Element on Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, dom, scroll, dom-events

I have a floating `img` that user can move around with pressed left mouse button; but I also want to zoom-in and zoom-out an image when user tries to scroll it.

I can't find proper events for this like `onscrollforeward` and `onscrollbackward`.

```
/* Here I want to zoom-in an image.
*/ image.onscrollforeward = function( e ) { ... };

/* And here to zoom-out.
*/ image.onscrollbackward = function( e ) { ... };
```

Comment: @Rishab first of all, I can't open your link, it's just a blank page for me. And second: I do not want to use bloated jQuery or anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't fully understand your question but i do know a way to detect if the user is scrolling up or down.

Maybe this snippet can help you out.

```js
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  // print "false" if direction is down and "true" if up
  console.log(this.oldScroll > this.scrollY);
  this.oldScroll = this.scrollY;
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  height: 1500px;
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="pixelkitten">
</div>
```

**EDIT**
I've changed the javascript a bit, this should now be able to help you.

```
const image = document.querySelector('img');

image.onscrollforeward = function( e ) { ... };

image.onscrollbackward = function( e ) { ... };    

image.onwheel = function _image__onwheel( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.deltaY < 0) this.onscrollforeward( e );
    else this.onscrollbackward( e );
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work when I assigning `onscroll` on `img` element. What I exactly want to get: https://2ch.hk/b/ (18+); just click on any image on this site and try to scroll.

Comment: I even tried to set `overflow: scroll` on my image element — results are the same.

Comment: In that case, you want to make the image bigger based on the user input scroll.
my answer did check the scroll user input.
I will edit my answer give me 5 minutes

Comment: Still doesn't work: it's just scrolling my page and I'm getting no output to console. :(

Comment: And this doesn't work only in Firefox. It works well in Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact code I will use for my case:

```
const image = document.getElementById('floatingImage');

image.zoom = 1;

image.onwheel = function _image__onwheel( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this[ e.deltaY < 0 ? 'onscrollforeward' : 'onscrollbackward' ]();
};

image.onscrollforeward = function _image__onscrollforeward( ) {
    this.style.transform = `scale(${ ++this.zoom })`;
};

image.onscrollbackward = function _image__onscrollbackward( ) {
    this.style.transform = `scale(${ --this.zoom })`;
};
```